# Flash music player with user access and database

Tags: xml, database, actionscript-3, user-interface

I am fairly new to actionscript 3, and coding in general, and I am trying to build a music application with a user account system, using which each different user can access their own music files.

I have found many tutorials online on how to create music players and playlists, user login systems, but nothing that combines these into one application.

My question is, what would be the best way to go about creating something like this? Some similar examples would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at FLAMPlayer - at least you will get an idea of the db and php end of things.